# d3.js zoom behavior: changing the scale while keeping translation consistent

Tags: d3.js, zooming, scale

I'm using the [d3 zoom behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) for zooming/dragging but the zoom steps are to coarse for my taste. Of course I can simply "rescale the scale" but then the x/y translation (which is computed such that the point under the cursor remains fixed) is wrong. How can I fix the translation?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to recompute the translation needed to keep that point fixed, but for the modified scale. For a given translation *T* and scaling *s* the fixed point *F* is mapped to

> (1) *P* = *T* + *s F*.

So when *P* should remain unchanged while changing the scaling from *s* to *s'* we also need to change the translation from *T* to *T'*. So our condition is

> (2) *P'* = *P* <=> *T'* + *s' F* = *T* + *s F*.

So our new translation *T'* is computed as

> (3) *T'* = *T* + (*s*-*s'*) *F*.

But we actually don't know *F* and so cannot compute *T'* right away. But *F* can be computed from the old and new (returned by the zoom behavior) translation and scaling as

> (4) *F* = (*T'*-*T*)/(*s*-*s'*).

If we now *change* the scaling to some other value *s''* we can compute the translation *T''* needed for that modified scaling as (use Eq. 4 in Eq. 3)

> (5) *T''* = *T* + (*s*-*s''*)(*T'*-*T*)/(*s*-*s'*).

Now you can set *s''* and *T''* as new values in you zoom behavior

> your_zoom_behavior.scale(changed_scale);
>
> your_zoom_behavior.translate([changed_x_translate, changed_y_translate]);

As you can see, *T''* is just *T'* if *s''* is *s'*. And it's *NaN* if *s* is *s'*, that is, if the scale actually didn't change – you have to check for this.